# Keep font size from Visual Studio to Word

Tags: visual-studio, ms-word, font-size, word-2010

I can verify that the font size in VS2010 is `10`, but when I copy it to Word2010, it all changes to `9.5`. No big deal but a little bit annoying. Any idea why and how to fix?

Comment: I had to do a double take on that one. But are right the color coding copied over, the font copies over, but the size is 0.5pt smaller

Comment: Have you got the default paste in Word set to (from memory) "keep source formatting"?

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge Thanks! Yes, I have verified that **Word Options - Advanced - Pasting from other programs** is set to _Keep Source Formatting (Default)_

Comment: On my new machine, this is no longer the case, although everything I can think of remains the same. No wonder somebody down vote this... :[ And thanks @JamesMohler for making me feel like not a complete idiot.